Whitney's strong embedding theorem for Manifolds with Boundary
I have a question on a remark from wikipedia on Whitney's strong embedding theorem:

The general outline of the proof is to start with an immersion $f: M\to \mathbb {R} ^{2m}$ with transverse self-intersections. These are known to exist from Whitney's earlier work on the weak immersion theorem. Transversality of the double points follows from a general-position argument. The idea is to then somehow remove all the self-intersections. If $M$ has boundary, one can remove the self-intersections simply by isotoping $M$ into itself (the isotopy being in the domain of $f$), to a submanifold of $M$ that does not contain the double-points. [...]

Question: Could somebody fill with details the part how the mentioned intermediate reduction step via appropriate isotopy works if $M$ is assumed to have boundary, justifying that it suffice next to treat only the case $M$ without boundary?
It seems that if $M$ has boundary $\partial M$ there is a canonical way to remove the self-intersections with certain special isotopy which takes $M$ to ifself, but without the intersection points, which seemingly only works if $M$ has boundary. Does such explicit isotopy arise as a kind of generalization of Alexander's trick? Would like somebody sketch the idea of such isotopy?

No, this is unrelated to the Alexander trick. Did you understand the proof of the strong embedding theorem in the case when the boundary is empty? The Wikipedia article is missing the connectedness assumption when discussing the case of manifolds with boundary.

@MoisheKohan: The proof I'm familar with is from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds; Chap 6, lemma 6.13 and exercise 9-14. but it seems that it approaches the boundary case differently applying connected sum method to it reducing to case without boundary. But I doubt that this is the approach wikipedia is refering to above.

Yes, it is different. You connect each intersection point with $\partial M$ by a simple arc and then remove a small tubular neighborhood of this arc from the manifold. This can be done via an isotopy.

@MoisheKohan: Nice, is this also the approach from Whitney's original papers or a modified one? If the latter is the case, do you have a reference? (have admittedly meanwhile skimmed over nearly 6 books + even more scripts containing this theorem (as strong form) but no one uses this argument)

I do not know, but, most likely, it is, since it is very similar (but much simpler) to the Whitney trick.

but coming back again to the concrete realization of this isotopy. So say we have picked for any intersection point an arc between it and some point at boundary, and we take around each small enough tubular nbd. Firstly, does this arc - except its endpoints - goes else through $M$ or only the ambient mfd $\Bbb R^n$? And finally how does it give rise to an isotopy resolving the intersections? Drawing analogy to Whitney trick essentially we embedded a disc whose boundary lies on the mfd and contains the intersections such we could resolve these by "moving" certain part of the mfd along the inner

of this embedded disc, this is the Whitney trick heuristically phrased. But I not got completely the picture of the construction with boundary you described. Espefially how the tubular nbhd enters into the picture to find this isogeny? Does it have something to do with that to resolve the intersection we can construct the isogeny - in rather good controlled way - inside the tubular nbhds of the arcs?

It is the same as on the Whitney trick: The arc is in $M$, not in the image of $M$. As for "resolving the intersection": You have two points in $M$ with the same image at the beginning. After isotopy, one of these points disappeared. Then you continue inductive. And I do not know which isogeny you are referring to.

@MoisheKohan: everywhere meant "isotopy", sorry bit unconcentrated

@MoisheKohan: yes I think I see, so its like "drilling" through the mfd  along the arc "entering into it" at the boundary point to which the arc connects the point which becomes intersection point in image, right?

Right...........


Here is the key ingredient in the construction. It takes place entirely in the manifold $M$. Suppose that $M$ is a connected manifold with nonempty boundary, $a$ is a smooth arc (embedded) in $M$, one end of which is at $\partial M$ and the other is at some point $p$ in the interior of $M$. Let $U$ be a tubular neighborhood of $a$ in $M$ (one needs to be a bit careful with the definition of what it means at the  point $p$). Then there exists a smooth family of embeddings $g_t: M\to M, t\in [0,1]$, which are all equal to the identity map outside of $U$, such that $g_0=id_M$ and the image of $g_1$ is disjoint from $a$.

Now, suppose you are given an immersion $f: M\to \mathbb R^N$ such that
$$
E=\{x\in M: f^{-1}f(x)\ne x\}
$$
is finite, disjoint from $\partial M$ and for every $x\in M, f^{-1}f(x)$ consists of at most two points. Then $E$ has even number of points matched in pairs, $x_i, x_i', i=1,...,k$. For each $i$  you pick an arc $a_i$ connecting $x_i$ to $\partial M$ so that the arcs are pairwise disjoint and each $a_i$ is disjoint from $E\setminus \{x_i\}$; also pick pairwise disjoint tubular neighborhoods $U_i$ of the arcs $a_i$ so that points $x_j'$ do not belong to any of these neighborhoods. Define a smooth family of self-maps $g_t: M\to M$ using maps as in Part 1 for each $U_i$. The maps $g_t$ are the identity outside of all $U_i$'s. Then the image $g_1(M)$ is a smooth manifold $M'\subset M$ such that $M'$ misses all the points $x_1,...,x_k$. The restriction of your map $f$ to $M'$ is not 1-1.

Lastly, take the composition $f\circ g_1: M\to \mathbb R^N$.



on 2.: Can it be always assured that this set $E$ is finite? Clearly, eg by Sard's thm this set must have measure zero, but how can we assure that it is even finite? Or do we need to impose it as additional assumption?

I was thinking only about compact case. In general, one should say "closed and discrete." @user267839
